# Executing curl from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, curl

Is there a way to execute curl from Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nope. You'll need to look at using Ajax/XMLHttpRequest instead. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Answer (score 4):

It depends of which environment is running javascript, if you mean from the browser, nop, it's not possible.

But if it's from Node.js, yes it's possible using native modules. Take a look at: https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl

Code example:

```
var Curl = require( 'node-libcurl' ).Curl;

var curl = new Curl();

curl.setOpt( 'URL', 'http://www.google.com' );
curl.setOpt( 'FOLLOWLOCATION', true );

curl.on( 'end', function( statusCode, body, headers ) {

    console.info( statusCode );
    console.info( '---' );
    console.info( body.length );
    console.info( '---' );
    console.info( this.getInfo( 'TOTAL_TIME' ) );

    this.close();
});

curl.on( 'error', function ( err, errCode ) {

    //do something

    this.close();
});

curl.perform();
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author, it's a modified version of another module: https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl.*

Comment: how can we write the curl code for  `curl -k https://<username>:<userToken>@<url>/api/json?pretty=true/`, is it possible to pass all these params?.

Comment: that is just the URL, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what curl you are talking about. You are probably asking about cURL, but if you are asking about the Curl programming language, then the answer is yes. You can invoke Curl methods on an object in an embedded Curl subapplet using the applet_invoke method. There are examples of this in the subapplet examples that are included in the Curl Developer's Guide.