# How can I send a curl request from javascript?

Tags: javascript, curl

I would like to send this

```
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: key=<MY API KEY>" \
     -d '{ "notification": {"title": "Hello world", "body": "you got a new message", "icon": "icon/path","click_action" : "page/path"},"to" : "<DEVICE TOKEN>"}'
```

from a js file to wherever I want. Considering the ideas you are giving me bellow, now I'm trying with this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Authorization': '<APY KEY>',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
            },
            data: {
                'title': 'Hello world!', 
                'body': 'you got a new message', 
                'icon': 'icon/path', 
                'click_action' : 'page/path', 
                'to' : '<DEVICE TOKEN>',
            },
            success: function (result) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (error) {
               alert("Cannot get data");
            }
        });
```

but I'm getting this error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: The error message does not mean your request, so you don't have to put these headers in your request. Instead it refers to the response from firebase, which you are trying to access. To enable CORS, you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing curl from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804639/executing-curl-from-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Curl doesn't exist in JavaScript, instead you can use XMLHttpRequest. To make it even more easy, you can use jQuery to send an AJAX request.

Here is some example code:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://yourdomain.com/example.php",
  data: {
    api_key: "xxxxxxxx"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //do something when request is successfull
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: yeah but that's the thing, I don't want to use any php in the process, any other way?

Comment: You can use the AJAX request on any resource url, this doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: yep, thanks for the idea, I'm implementing this right now, but still having some " header access control " problems

Comment: You need to add the headers to the resource you are trying to load using AJAX. But this is the JavaScript client-side script.